# Scalabilty issues with Restful WCF

Tags: wcf, sql-server-2008, iis-7, wcf-data-services

Hi I have built a simple WCF application I am using to query data back and forth from Mobile app.
Everything else works Fine But When I try to Upload large binary video upload it gives me weird error, I am successfully able to upload binary streams upto 3-4 MB but larger than that 
I get one of the following error randomly

1.

```
<html>

   <BODY>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big><strong></strong></big><BR>
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>Network Error (tcp_error)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
A communication error occurred: ""
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>
For assistance, contact your network support team.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY>
</html>
```

2.

```
<html>

<body>

<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>

<div id="content">

 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>

  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>

  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>

 </fieldset></div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
   <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding transferMode="Streamed" maxBufferSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" openTimeout="05:25:00" closeTimeout="00:25:00" sendTimeout="00:25:00" receiveTimeout="0:25:00"
                 name="webBinding"
        />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
       <service behaviorConfiguration="RestBehavior" name="EyePlots.Videos">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding"
           contract="EyePlots.IVideos" />
      </service>
</services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RestBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100"
    maxConcurrentInstances="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Could it be issue with the scalability of the system? I can post my code snippets if you guys want? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 4 megs is an IIS throttle.

Have you set (IIS7+)

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Here's a post listing out some more throttles to try opening up. [WCF problem with uploading large file, hosted in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317794/wcf-problem-with-uploading-large-file-hosted-in-iis)

Comment: If this isn't your problem, please post your config.

Comment: Adding a link listing out more throttles that allowed the answerer to upload large files.

Comment: Thanks adding  `<system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="4800" maxRequestLength="500000000"/> </system.web>`
 fixed the issue!